# Copy CStringArray data to unsigned char array

Tags: mfc

I have CStringArray data and I want to assign all data in unsigned char array.

```
CStringArray m_arrSecurityAES;
unsigned char private_key[16];
m_arrSecurityAES contains data as (00, 01....0E 0F).
```

I want to assign this data in private_key in `Hex` format as (`0x00`, `0x01`, ..., `0x0E`, `0x0F`).

Can someone please help me how to assign it?

Comment: A `CStringArray` is an array of `CStrings` , but from your description `m_arrSecurityAES` looks rather as an array of bytes. Your question is very unclear. Please elaborate and [edit] the question. Espewcially show how `m_arrSecurityAES` is filled.

Comment: ok. I will make it more simple for you. I have one CString data as 0E, I want to assign it to unsigned char data.                                                                                                                     CString value1 = _T("0E");                                                                              unsigned char value2;                                                                                                     I am expecting value 2 as 0x0E. please help me how to assign value1 to value2?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and put all clarifications _there_

Comment: Your are probably looking for [`strtoul`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtoul/)

Answer (score 0):

You want this:

```
  CStringArray m_arrSecurityAES;
  m_arrSecurityAES.Add(_T("00"));
  m_arrSecurityAES.Add(_T("01"));
  m_arrSecurityAES.Add(_T("0A"));  // only three values in this sample

  unsigned char private_key[16];

  for (int i = 0; i < m_arrSecurityAES.GetSize(); i++)
  {
    private_key[i] = (unsigned char)_tcstoul(m_arrSecurityAES[i].GetString(), NULL, 16);
  }
```

Comment: If you find the answer useful upvote and/or accept it.